# Connecting react native on Android emulator to express server

Tags: express, react-native, android-emulator

I've just started react native and I could run it using Expo XDE. The front end works properly but a problem occurs when the client(emulator) sends a 'GET' request to the server(nodejs-express).

A network error appears, what shall I do to connect the emulator to the express server? I used the localhost ip, is this the right way?
The error was about connectivity between my mobile and my computer. I used localhost ip, but when I replaced it by the computer local ip, it worked. Also if you use android studio, you can use 10.0.0.2 or 10.0.0.3 for genymotion.

### client

```
 import React from "react";
 import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
 import axios from "axios";

 export default class App extends React.Component {
  fetchData() {
    alert("clicked");
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000")
        .then(function(res) {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>

            <Button
                onPress={this.fetchData}
                title="Learn More"
                color="#841584"
                Label="Learn more"
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
}
});
```

### server

```
   const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
var Port=process.env.PORT||3000;

const app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.listen(Port,()=>console.log(`server started at 3000`));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    //res.send({data:"data"})
    console.log(console.log("request is recieved"))
})
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you make the API call ?
Please update your question with more specific details that would help people understand the issue better.
Also if the request goes through successfully, I see you have commented out the statement to pass on the response.
```//res.send({data:"data"})```.

Comment: Thanks, @sghosh968. It was a long time since I posted the question. The error occurs because I used localhost ip.

Comment: great, glad you figured it out. :)

Comment: Thank you, @sghosh968. Do you find the question clear, or I should clarify it more?. I need to get votes for the question!

Comment: Yes, its clear. @nada-ghanem